# firestore unavailable The service is currently unavailable

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

> [Error: [firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.]

I encountered this sudden error with the same code which worked fine yesterday
This error occurred when I tried to get data from firebase firestore
using these versions

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.7.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
```

Comment: Can you check this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70607415/18265570) once?

Comment: Yes in my case all calls to firebase firestore are giving this error and firebase auth is working fine also 2 days before firestore is working good with this same code I don't even touched the code

Comment: Where are you running your code? Emulator or Physical device? Make sure you the device has internet connection.

Comment: Emulator, it has an internet connection as firebase auth is working

Comment: you mentioned *firebase firestore are giving this error* only firestore giving error? you mean firestore [calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/**` only not working? rest [firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) only working?can you inspect your app in browser and see any other status code in network other than 200 while using firestore?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Android Emulator v 31.3.10
Turning off wifi in the emulator and turning on its data connection
works for me. Check these for further details.

[Firebase doesn't work on Android Studio Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370728/firebase-doesnt-work-on-android-studio-emulator/73395525#73395525)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the internet was switched off on my physical android device.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your AVD's Cellular settings and change network strength from moderate to great. Issue will be solved.